# Best practice accessing document object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, barcode-scanner

Is it bad practice to access the document Object directly when working with a framework like React.

I am using an external barcode scanner and I want to detect when number is scanned and populate a specific field.  I want to avoid tracking what field is in focus.

#### Here is my code

```
 render(){
    ....
    document.onkeypress = (e) => {
      e = e || window.event;
      const digit = e.key;
      if(e.target.nodeName === 'BODY' && digit.match(/[0-9]/i)){
        console.log(digit);
      }
    };
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend adding event listeners to the document or window when using an SPA like React or Vue etc... that said - The React docs do provide some information on this - maybe where you place your listener' is more of an important question rather than in your `render` method etc https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html

Comment: I sense an [X/Y problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need a `keypress` handler on `document` in your component?

Answer (score 3):

`document.onkeypress` is likely to be poor practice regardless of whether you're using React. Instead, `document.addEventListener("keypress", ...)` (and be sure to do it only once.)

Separately, hooking up event handlers in `render` would certainly not be best practice. **If** you need to hook up a handler to `document` for some reason, you'd do that in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) (and you'd remove it in [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount)).

Comment: The reason for needed to detect key press is that the barcode scanner acts as a HID keyboard.  The app is planned to be used on a Kiosk of sorts.  I want to limit mouse usage and avoid having a user select a field to populate with barcode.  
I will try moving to componentDidMount